# Merge Port tags, Report tags, Portable tags

Tags: discussion, retag-request

I found these 3 groups of similar tags that I think can be merged and synonymized:

---

Port  related tags:

- [port](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/port) x 377
- [ports](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ports) x 61

---

Report  related tags:

- [report](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/report) x 20
- [reporting](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/reporting) x 18
- [bug-report](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/bug-report) x 6

---

Portable related tags:

- [portable](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/portable) x 140 – the tag wiki mentions portable apps, but some questions are about portable computers or devices
- [portable-apps](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/portable-apps) x 37

---

Comment: I'd merge `[ports]` into `[port]`, but should we come up with something more specific than `[port]`? At the moment this applies to computer ports (USB, etc.), network ports (TCP, UDP), and probably ports of software (think MacPorts, etc.)

Comment: @slhck What we did on [unix.se]: http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/604/splitting-the-ports-tag, http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/997/please-rename-ports-to-bsd-ports-and-what-to-do-about-ports

Comment: I think that "report" and "reporting" can be safely merged, but "bug-report" is a different thing. You can have reports that aren't related to bugs.

Answer (score 1):

The last part with [portable](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/portable) and [portable-apps](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/portable-apps) should get some attention once more.
I recommend to make a synonym or merge them.

The tag wiki of both tags refers to the same: portable = no software installation

I clicked through most of the [portable](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/portable) questions and those who aren't referring to a portable software misused the tag. It should be removed from them.

---

Examples for misused portable tags are:

- [A script so that you don't forget your usb drive on a public computer](https://superuser.com/questions/78816/a-script-so-that-you-dont-forget-your-usb-drive-on-a-public-computer)
- [Does a portable secondary laptop LCD monitor exist?](https://superuser.com/questions/76214/does-a-portable-secondary-laptop-lcd-monitor-exist)
- [Can I charge a computer through its USB port?](https://superuser.com/questions/94170/can-i-charge-a-computer-through-its-usb-port-which-brand-models)

If needed I would check all of them and remove the tag

Answer (score 1):

- [port](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/port) and [ports](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ports) are similar enough to merge.  I don't see any obvious differences.
- [report](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/report) and [reporting](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/reporting) are similar enough to merge as well, but [bug-report](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/bug-report) doesn't necessarily mean the same as [report](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/report).  For example, a user may want to generate a report from a set of data in a document.  [report](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/report) would work, but [bug-report](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/bug-report) would not.  In fact, [bug-report](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/bug-report) seems to be more of a programming topic and it may be better to delete the tag altogether, since it isn't widely used.
- Questions tagged [portable](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/portable) that are related to portable apps should have the tag removed and replaced with [portable-apps](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/portable-apps) if it is not already present.  To avoid confusion, the tag [portable](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/portable) probably should be renamed to [portable-device](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/portable-device) (though this may not be a good idea, since "portable device" is really ambiguous).

Of course, in all cases, when a tag doesn't really describe the question, it should be removed.